# XML variable tag names

Tags: xml, xsd

I have been tasked with writing an xsd, for an xml file format that my company has created.

Unfortunately one of the tags contains two variables, here is an example of the tag

```
<to_1.1.1.0_24>
```

The 1.1.1.0 is an ip address and as such can change, and the 24 is the netmask. 
Is there anyway of expressing this within an xsd document.

Many Thanks

David

Comment: It sounds like the original designer of this XML didn't like XML's verbosity, and tried to get clever.  Big mistake.  It will be painful dealing with this XML in the rest of the XML ecosystem, as you are now seeing trying to write an XSD for it.

Comment: I am now seeing great difficulty in writing the XSD, which I think I am going to delay, until I can refactor this area of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The tag itself shouldn't contain variable data. That should be split out into either attributes or elements. For example:

```
<to ip="1.1.1.0" netmask="24" />
```

or:

```
<to>
    <ip>1.1.1.0</ip>
    <netmask>24</netmask>
</to>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping this wasn't the case. This is what I suspected as the decoding of the xml, is quite complex. Unfortunatly I didn't design this part of the software or xml structure.

Comment: "We don't do X, do Y"

Answer (score 1):

Use the `xsd:any` element.  That will validate this kind of element.

However, it won't fail validation for anything else, but that's the kind of tradeoff you have to make when you crowbar this sort of thing into XML.

Answer (score 0):

No. And in general this is very bad form for an XML document as it makes parsing it considerably less straightforward than it ought to be. Really it should be something like

```
<to network="1.1.1.0" netmask-bit="24">...</to>
```

or something like that