# XSD variable element names

Tags: xsd

Is it possible in XSD to name an element dynamically?

I have a complexType with a varying (but limited) number of elements (x-n), each of which has a complicated substructure. I can copy and paste one (x-1) and just change the number for the name of each of the copies (x-2, x3, and so on), but it'd be cleaner if I didn't have to.

For example, as it is now:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unq1" elementFormDefault="q1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="r1">
        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="w-s">
                <xs:complexType><xs:sequence maxOccurs="4">
                    <xs:element name="x-1" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
                            <!-- long tedious substructure goes here -->
                        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="x-2" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
                            <!-- long tedious substructure goes here -->
                        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="x-3" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
                            <!-- long tedious substructure goes here -->
                        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="x-4" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
                            <!-- long tedious substructure goes here -->
                        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Looking through w3schools now (https://www.w3schools.blog/xsd-xml-schema-definition-tutorial), the answer is not jumping out at me yet, and it's starting to look like the answer is "No.".

Comment: You can certainly save yourself from copying/pasting that complex type, if that is the same, for all those `x-something` elements, by declaring it with e.g. `<xs:complexType name="foo"><xs:sequence> <!-- long tedious substructure goes here --></xs:sequence></xs:complexType>` and just using e.g `<xs:element name="x-1" type="foo" minOccurs="0"/>`. But there is no way in a DTD or an XSD schema to declare all those different `x-something` elements, other than spelling them out. Or to consider making that number an attribute value of an element named `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by these stackoverflows, the answer appears to be "Not only no, but also you're wrong for asking" :-p

[xml schema list of incremental element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477477/xml-schema-list-of-incremental-element-name)

[Can't design xsd schema - because of a variable element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477340/cant-design-xsd-schema-because-of-a-variable-element-name)

[XML variable tag names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960478/xml-variable-tag-names)

The better solution is to restructure the XSD so that the x-n element has a sub-element indicating the value of n, like so:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unq1" elementFormDefault="q1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="r1">
        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="w-s">
                <xs:complexType><xs:sequence maxOccurs="4">
                    <xs:element name="x" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="x-number">
                            <!-- long tedious substructure goes here -->
                        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can copy and paste one (x-1) and just change the number

If each element `x-n` has the same content then you should use the same tag name for all of these tags. That will require a change in the XML format, so I would also recommend that you stop using this style:

`<element name='x-n' ...>`

...and start using this instead:

`<x index="n">`

This will make your life much easier because XML schema expects the tag name to indicate the type of content.

I understand that you may not be able to change the XML format, but I think it's important to point out that your current style of XML is not best practice.